# Writing a program to find those numbers which are divisible by 7 and a multiple of 5, between 1500 and 2700 (both included), using Python

Tags: python-3.x

What I have tried:

```
def find_numbers(lower_bound, upper_bound):
   
  results=[]
   
  for i in range(lower_bound,upper_bound):
     
    if (i % 7 == 0 and i % 5 !=0):
          results.append(i)
    return results

lower_bound = int( input("Lower bound to search for numbers: ") )

upper_bound = int( input("Upper bound to search for numbers: ") )

found_numbers = find_numbers(lower_bound, upper_bound)

print("The numbers that are divisible by 7 but not by 5 

are:\n{}".format(found_numbers))
```

Comment: Divisible by 7 and multiple of 5 means the number is divisible by both 7 and 5. You sure with the question??

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of your return statement outside the for loop. When you call the function, when the for loop is run for the first time, it checks only first element and returns it. If you change the position of return statement outside the loop, it will return the list after the completion of the loop

```
def find_numbers(lower_bound, upper_bound):
    results=[]
    for i in range(lower_bound,upper_bound):
        if (i % 7 == 0 and i % 5 !=0):
            results.append(i)
    return results

lower_bound = int( input("Lower bound to search for numbers: ") )

upper_bound = int( input("Upper bound to search for numbers: ") )

found_numbers = find_numbers(lower_bound, upper_bound)

print("The numbers that are divisible by 7 but not by 5 are:\n{}".format(found_numbers))
```